# Page scrolls up using JQuery fadeIn - fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay

Hi I use the following code to create a slideshow with multiple DIV elements:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
function fadeContent() {
  $(".slideshow .asset-abstract:first").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
    fadeContent();
  });
}
fadeContent();
```

The slideshow works properly but there's a problem. When the delay(2000) trigger a fadeIn-fadeOut, the page scrolls up!

What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I think when the element fades out it does not take a real estate on the page. The element beneath it will take its place and you feel like the page scrolled. You can have a wrapper to the element you are trying to fadeIn/fadeOut and provide an appropriate height to this wrapper element. But this is not a good UX because when the element will fadeOut there will be empty section on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the fadeOut method ends op settings `display:none;` on the element.

If you force display block in css this will not happen:

Css:

```
.slideshow .asset-abstract:first-child {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Then what is the use of fading out?